# Number of tries to guess M-1 letters from M-letters-code.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, puzzle

There are N letters in an alphabet. There is a combination lock, the code to it consists from M different letters.

You can input M letters combination to try to open the lock.

If you guess at least M-1 letters from the code correctly the lock will be opened. The order does not matter (ACEB combination will open lock with ABCD code).

**How many** tries you need to guarantee that lock will be opened? [How to find list of combinations you need to try?]

I am especially interested in the case N = 32, M = 4.

Comment: Where did you find this puzzle? Perhaps try looking at smaller cases of $M$ first, like $M=2$. You'd have to try $N-1$ possile combinations.

Comment: You could then look at $M=N-2$

Comment: Can you clarify "The order does not matter"?
E.g. if the code is $ABCD$ and I enter $ABCE$ the lock will clearly open,
but what when I enter $ACBD$ or $ACBE$? Will it open?

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk, It will.

Comment: I am not sure if the general case of this problem has ever been solved.
Its 'translation' to graph theory asks for the domination number of a Johnson graph. What exactly are you looking for? A closed formula for the general case, answers for specific values of m and n, upper/lower bounds?

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk, i think this is a new problem, yes. I'm looking for answer when N=32,M=4.

Comment: The graph you are looking at has 35960 vertices and is regular of degree 112,
so you need at least 114 attempts to guarantee that the lock opens,
but that is just a lower bound.
I can't help any further, sorry.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk: Would you explain how you arrived at 114?

Comment: In a $k$-regular graph with $n$ vertices each vertex dominates
at most $k+1$ vertices, so a dominating set has at least $\lceil\frac{n}{k+1}\rceil$ vertices.
In this case that is 114.
I suggest to add the tag "graph-theory" to your question.
Maybe a pro over there knows the answer.